# Understanding Access-Control-Allow-Origin and caching

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, http-headers, cors

I have an issue with what I believe to be caching of the origin header when querying the WordPress API. However, I am struggling to work out exactly what is happening and how I can fix it.

First - here's what's happening:

I have a HubSpot page that queries via ajax the WordPress API and specifically the endpoints added by the WP API Menus plugin - I then build the menu so that when updated in WordPress by the client (or one of the marketing team) - the menu is updated on the HubSpot pages too.

The HubSpot page is on a subdomain of the WordPress site, and initially the WordPress site had the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin added with ***just*** the subdomain URL explicitly set.

If I browse to the edit screen within HubSpot - the main menu doesn't load, but the second call (for a different menu) succeeds. The error for the main menu is as follows:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'http://subdomain.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'https://preview.hs-sites.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The http://subdomain.example.com being the URL of the live page. Strangely the actual URL of the preview page is not https://preview.hs-sites.com - but I assume this may be because perhaps preview loads in an iframe.

Now, when I then go to the live URL, the same thing happens - the first call errors, but the second succeeds. This time the error is as follows:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
>   'https://preview.hs-sites.com' that is not equal to the supplied
>   origin. Origin 'http://subdomain.example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

---

> Question 1 - is this because the origin has been cached by the
>   WordPress site?

I have now added both http://subdomain.example.com and https://preview.hs-sites.com to the **allowed_http_origins** filter within WordPress - as follows:

```
add_filter( 'allowed_http_origins', 'my_add_origins' );
function my_add_origins($origins) {
    $origins[] = 'https://preview.hs-sites.com';
    $origins[] = 'http://subdomain.example.com';
    return $origins;
}
```

> Question 2: Regardless of the presumed caching - why is
>   https://preview.hs-sites.com not acceptable if it has been added to
>   the allowed origins?

I was unsure how to test the above function - so I also tried the following:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');
    add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function($value) {
        $domains = [
            'https://preview.hs-sites.com',
            'http://subdomain.example.com'
        ];
        $allowed = get_http_origin();
        if ($allowed && (in_array($allowed, $domains))) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:" . esc_url_raw($allowed));
        } elseif (!$allowed) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://subdomain.example.com");
        }
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');

        return $value;
    });
});
```

But the exact same errors occur.

> Question 3: Could somebody please explain the process that takes place
>   in this situation and what the errors are saying - specifically where
>   they are getting their values from - is origin the current page? And
>   the 'The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value' ... - this
>   value is being set by whatever has been set as the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in WordPress - correct?

**Note** I have also tried setting no-cache header in the ajax request, but this errors because of the preflight request. I've also added a random querystring to the request, which has no effect.

I'd like to avoid adding a wildcard value as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header for security reasons. And I'd really like to understand what's going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `Vary` response header with the value `Origin` to the server response.

That should have the  effect of causing any browser to skip its cache and make a new network request when the value of the `Origin` request header is different from the `Origin` value of the request it cached from.

For a bit more info, see [the MDN article on the `Vary` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary).

> The `Vary` HTTP response header determines how to match future request
>   headers to decide whether a cached response can be used rather than
>   requesting a fresh one from the origin server. It is used by the
>   server to indicate which headers it used when selecting a
>   representation of a resource in a content negotiation algorithm.