# cors failing for subdomains

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, axios

CORS not working properly for domain and subdomain.
I've a single NodeJS server hosted at **https://api.example.com**
I've two ReactJS Clients

Client 1. **https://example.com**

Client 2. **https://subdomain.example.com**

I've configured Client 1 to force www so that a single origin is used for Client 1.
When I open Clien1 that works fine.
When I open Client2 I get the error that

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/someAPI' from origin 'https://subdomain.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin

When I press Ctrl+F5 then it works fine but after that If I refresh Client1 then the error comes at Client1

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/someAPI' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://subdomain.example.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

Now When I press Ctrl+F5 at Client1 then it works fine but the same error goes to the Client2.

My nodeJS server is configured as follows

```
var whitelist = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://subdomain.example.com'];
    getCorsCoptions(req, callback) {
    var getOriginValue = () => {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('origin')) !== -1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        log.error(__filename, 'Not allowed by CORS', origin);
        return false;
      }
    }
    var corsOptions = {
      origin: getOriginValue(),
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      credentials: true,
      preflightContinue: false,,
      allowedHeaders:["Content-Type","X-Requested-With","X-HTTP-Method-Override","Accept"]
    }
    callback(null, corsOptions)
  }

app.use('*', cors(this.getCorsCoptions));
app.options('*', cors(this.getCorsCoptions));
```

I'm using axios at React Client sides as follows

```
get(url: string) {
    return Axios.get(url, {
      withCredentials: true
    }).then((res: any) => {
      if (res) {
        return res.data;
      }
      return {};
    });
}

post(url: string, data: any) {
    let requestHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    return Axios.post(url, data, {
      headers: requestHeaders
      , withCredentials: true
    }).then((res: any) => {
      if (res) {
        return res.data;
      }
      return {};
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you using `express` on the server?

Comment: yes, using express on server

Comment: I've posted an answer. Try setting your corsOptions.origin to the array of URL strings that you want to work

Comment: Not sure but it sounds like maybe you want to try adding a `Vary: Origin` response header to the response. See the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46735000/441757 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46067554/441757 and see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. The browser was caching origin.
Solved this problem by adding the following header in response

```
Cache-Control: no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate
```

I've also added `Vary: Origin` but i think it didn't solve the problem
I've managed cors as follows

```
var whitelist = ['https://www.example.com', 'https://subdomain.example.com'];
router.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) != -1) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
    }
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ["Content-Type","X-Requested-With","X-HTTP-Method-Override","Accept"]);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
    res.header("Cache-Control", "no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate");
    res.header("Vary", "Origin");
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
    res.status(200).send("");
      return;
    }
    next();
});
```

where router is express.Router()

I hope that someone find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using express. Based on their docs, you can set origin to an array of strings or RegExp which should allow the origins that you want.

- https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

> origin: Configures the Access-Control-Allow-Origin CORS header.
>   Possible values:
>
> - Array - set origin to an array of valid origins.
>     Each origin can be a String or a RegExp. For example
>     ["http://example1.com", /.example2.com$/] will accept any request
>     from “http://example1.com” or from a subdomain of “example2.com”.

Based on that, updating `getOriginValue()` to the following might work for you:

```
var getOriginValue = () => {
  if (whitelist.indexOf(req.header('origin')) !== -1) {
    return whitelist; // Return array of strings
  } else {
    log.error(__filename, 'Not allowed by CORS', origin);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're calling your function, you need to just pass it to the middleware

```
var corsOptions = {
      origin: getOriginValue, // Not origin: getOriginValue()<-no parens,
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
      credentials: true,
      preflightContinue: false,,
      allowedHeaders:["Content-Type","X-Requested-With","X-HTTP-Method-Override","Accept"]
    }
```

Comment: You've noted a valid point, but that doesn't solve my problem